# AS3 adding and removing objects, is it a good idea?

Tags: actionscript-3

In AS3 I create a number of playing cards through a class that extends a sprite.

I then add and remove these to stage throughout the game.

I was wondering, is this the right way to do it? Is it processor intensive to keep adding and removing objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that when you say "adding and removing objects" you mean adding and removing to/from the stage.

It is more processor intensive to create and destroy the objects over and over than to add and remove to/from the stage. So I'd say that you're safe.

However, an alternative to adding and removing to the stage is to change the `visible` propety of your sprites. This is even less processor intensive and could be a suitable solution for you. Note that when an object is invisible, it's still there. It just doesn't show. See this question on StackOverflow: [visible property of DisplayObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684549/visible-property-of-displayobject)